# how to keep jpa session in the thread

Tags: spring, jpa

Now I use JPA in my web application. And I have a class like this:

```
class A {
    ...

    @OneToMany
    private List<B> list;
    ...
}
```

When it is in a HTTP request, I can use a.getList() successful. But in a schedule thread, it throws the exception:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: A.list, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

Can I keep the session in the schedule thread just like the http request thread?

Comment: What schedule thread actually does? Is this related to HTTP thread or just  a background `java.lang.Thread` ?

Comment: It is just a background thread. I use spring schedule to run the thread

Comment: Your thread should call a service method (`@Transactional(readOnly=true`) to get the entity `A` via DAO (`@Repository`) each time that thread is getting executed.

Comment: Thank you. I will test it later. Can you tell why would it work? I think the session will close just after the service method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, when spring handle the http request, it start the transaction by the interceptor `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewInterceptor` or the filter `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter`. So if we want to keep the session, we can start and commit the transaction by our self.

Here is the code:

```
public class BackendThread {

    @Autowired
    private PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager;

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message, byte[] pattern) {
    new TransactionTemplate(platformTransactionManager).execute(new TransactionCallback<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void doInTransaction(TransactionStatus transactionStatus) {
            ...
            your code here
            ...
            return null;
        }
    });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

TransactionTemplate is helpful if you use JPA. I didn't use it and created a session/transactions on my own in background thread, so that each task had its own environment:

Inject entity manager or get it from Spring context or pass it as reference:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

Then create a new entity manager, to avoid using a shared one:

```
EntityManager em = entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
```

Now you can start transaction and use Spring DAO, Repository, JPA, etc

```
private void save(EntityManager em) {

    try
    {         
        em.getTransaction().begin();                

        <your database changes>

        em.getTransaction().commit();                        
    }
    catch(Throwable th) {
        em.getTransaction().rollback();
        throw th;
    }        
}
```